# Getting data from time series as per start and end time

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I have 100 text files which contains time series starting and ending at different point of times. I want to extract the values for common period of time in the series.
Use the following code to generate the sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
D1 = data.frame(time = seq(ISOdatetime(2012, 6, 26, 3, 15, 00), 
                       length = 500, by = 900),
            value = rnorm(500))
D2 = data.frame(time = seq(ISOdatetime(2012, 6, 24, 5, 30, 00),
                       length = 541, by = 900),
            value = rnorm(541))
D3 = data.frame(time = seq(ISOdatetime(2012, 6, 23, 5, 45, 00),
                       length = 700, by = 900),
            value = rnorm(700))
```

This data will give you 3 time series starting and ending and different times. I wish to keep only the values for common time period and remove the rest. i.e.
if,

- 1st series starts with "2012-6-26 3:45:26" ends with "2012-8-07 4:45:26"
- 2nd with "2012-6-24 5:55:27"  ends with "2012-7-28 7:45:26"
- 3rd with "2012-6-23 5:04:30"  ends with "2012-7-27 4:45:26"

Then I wish to keep the data of intersection of the three time series i.e. data corresponding to:-

- start: "2012-6-26 3:45:26"
- end:"2012-7-27 4:45:26"
- for all the 3 series and remove the rest.

I searched SO and other websites but didn't find any solution. Need help on that.
How do I achieve that?

Comment: To what precision in time are you concerned with? Your calculations (15*60) are in 15 minute intervals, but the hypothetical start  times that you mention for the second and third series (5:55:27 and 5:04:30) are not. This could make merging difficult since by default merging would be done with exact time matches. There are probably other ways around instead of merging, but that's what comes to mind. After looking at my answer and this comment, is your data in a form that is easy to merge or is it in some other form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you need to familiarize yourself with the `xts` package. Convert your data frame to `xts` time series objects and use `merge`. `merge` will merge all values, so if you want values occurring in all, you can also use `na.omit`.

```
require(xts)
D1 = xts(d1$Value, d1$Time)
D2 = xts(d2$Value, d2$Time)
D3 = xts(d3$Value, d3$Time)
temp = merge(D1, D2, D3)
```

Here is some example output. For `head` and `tail`, note the presence of `NA` values.

```
head(temp)
#                              D1 D2 D3
# 2012-06-26 13:15:19 -0.50219235 NA NA
# 2012-06-26 13:30:19  0.13153117 NA NA
# 2012-06-26 13:45:19 -0.07891709 NA NA
# 2012-06-26 14:00:19  0.88678481 NA NA
# 2012-06-26 14:15:19  0.11697127 NA NA
# 2012-06-26 14:30:19  0.31863009 NA NA
tail(temp)
#                     D1 D2         D3
# 2012-07-04 05:45:19 NA NA  1.4799645
# 2012-07-04 06:00:19 NA NA -0.3942801
# 2012-07-04 06:15:19 NA NA -0.6767234
# 2012-07-04 06:30:19 NA NA -0.2425192
# 2012-07-04 06:45:19 NA NA  0.4547177
# 2012-07-04 07:00:19 NA NA  1.1712661
head(na.omit(temp))
#                             D1          D2          D3
# 2012-06-27 14:15:19 -0.3329234 -1.63230970  0.75619287
# 2012-06-27 14:30:19  1.3631137 -0.06299626 -1.36131851
# 2012-06-27 14:45:19 -0.4691473 -0.70544686 -0.60876462
# 2012-06-27 15:00:19  0.8428756 -0.31417818 -0.21174696
# 2012-06-27 15:15:19 -1.4579937 -0.26694627 -0.67847242
# 2012-06-27 15:30:19 -0.4003059  0.15315947  0.06665787
tail(na.omit(temp))
#                              D1         D2          D3
# 2012-07-01 16:45:19 -0.49419020  1.1911322  2.73143169
# 2012-07-01 17:00:19 -1.71111303  0.7613245  0.57057667
# 2012-07-01 17:15:19  0.04005805 -0.1210687  1.32083870
# 2012-07-01 17:30:19 -0.56114348 -1.2250590  0.09951626
# 2012-07-01 17:45:19 -2.55736206 -0.1637461 -0.39435301
# 2012-07-01 18:00:19 -0.69677881 -1.3138963  0.63649492
```